# ¿Cómo puedo detectar si esta bloqueado el permiso de javascript en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Tengo algunas funciones en javascript las cuales al yo bloquear el permiso de javascript de mi navegador no se están ejecutando, quiero saber si hay alguna forma de detectar cuando ese permiso esté bloqueado para después yo bloquear el acceso a mi aplicación web.

Comment: Puedes mostrar un mensaje entre las etiquetas `<noscript>mensaje</noscript>`.

Comment: Gracias, esa fue mi solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue agregar un mensaje dentro de la etiqueta `<noscript></noscript>`.

```
<noscript>
    <div id="noscript" style="background:red; padding: 10px">
        <span style="color:white">El sistema de Vales de Almacén funciona mejor con Javascript habilitado</span>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]